# Notation confusion in Hales's The Group Law for Edwards Curves

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, elliptic-curves

I have an issue undertanding some notation in Thomas Hales, *The Group Law for Edwards Curves*.  At page 6, he writes:

> We use the following rings: $R_0:=\mathbb{Z}[c,d]$ and $R_n := R_0[x_1,y_1,\ldots,x_n,y_n]$. We reintroduce the polynomial for the Edwards curve. Let $e(x,y) = x^2+cy^2 - 1 - dx^2y^2 \in R_0[x,y]$.
>
> We write $e_i = e(x_i,y_i)$ for the image of the polynomial in $R_j$, for $i \le j$, under $x \mapsto x_i$ and $y \mapsto y_i$.

I wonder how should I understand this quote. I would just say, relabel polynomial $e$ with $x \mapsto x_i$ and $y \mapsto y_i$. But in the quote it is like if he sees $e \in R_j$. Can anybody explain me this confusion?

Comment: There is a unique map $R_0[x,y]\to R_n$ mapping $x\to x_i, y\to y_i$, universality of polynomial rings, use it to map $e$, the result is $e_i$

Comment: @dan_fulea, i answered my question based on your idea, did I understand you correctly?

Comment: Yes, it is ok! You have anyway to work with the objects now, so some examples are maybe welcome, just to see that we both collect the same objects. For instance, for $n=5$ we have: $$\begin{aligned}e_1 &= x_1^2+cy_1^2-1-dx_1^2y_1^2&&\in R_0[x_1,y_1,\dots,x_5,y_5]\ ,\\e_2 &= x_2^2+cy_2^2-1-dx_2^2y_2^2&&\in R_0[x_1,y_1,\dots,x_5,y_5]\ ,\\e_3 &= x_3^2+cy_3^2-1-dx_3^2y_3^2&&\in R_0[x_1,y_1,\dots,x_5,y_5]\ ,\\e_4 &= x_4^2+cy_4^2-1-dx_4^2y_4^2&&\in R_0[x_1,y_1,\dots,x_5,y_5]\ ,\\e_5 &= x_5^2+cy_5^2-1-dx_5^2y_5^2&&\in R_0[x_1,y_1,\dots,x_5,y_5]\ .\end{aligned}$$ The text tried to describe it quickly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using @dan_fulea's idea. We know that given that the inclusion $i$ gives an homomorphism from $R_0$ to $R_n$, the universal property of polynomial rings gives that there exists a unique homomorphism $f_u$ from $R_0[x,y]$ to $R_n$ that satisfies: $f_u(x) = x_i$, $f_u(y) = y_i$ and $f_u(r_0) = i(r_0) = r_0$ for elements $r_o \in R_0$. This $f_u$ is if I'm not mistaken the evaluation.

The same argument can be applied for $R_j$ with $i \le j$ instead of $R_n$.

Comment: Yes! (It may be important to understand this "universal yoga" of polynomials and polynomial substitutions.)